# PartialChain: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority error in performancepoint dashboard designer

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth, reporting-services

when access PerformancePoint dashboard designer I got below error message in event viewer and unable to connect to SharePoint site collection.

An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:

Errors:
 PartialChain: A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.
RevocationStatusUnknown: The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
OfflineRevocation: The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.

site collection URL: https://www.siteurl.com
I open above url one of application server where performance point service run
when I did fiddler it is going to digcert site and how I avoid in the local server it is not checked certificate validation for with this site?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a functional internet connection (proxy settings are OK, etc.)? If you run Fiddler, do you see any failed web request (like timeout) in the direction of the revocation server?

Comment: in the event viewer i saw certificate errors and i added sharepoint certificate trusted root authority also $rootCert = (Get-SPCertificateAuthority).RootCertificate
$rootCert.Export("Cert") | Set-Content C:\Files\SPRootAuthority.cer -Encoding byte

Comment: i open above url one of application server where performance point service run
when i did fiddler it is going to digcert site and how i avoid in local server it is not check certificate validation for  with this site ?